# How to get the integer value from enumerize inside a rabl template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl, enumerize

I have the follow model using enumerize gem:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Enumerize
    enumerize :code, in: {dummy: 0, none: 1, panic: 2 }
end
```

This rabl file returns the strings "dummy", "none" and "panic:

```
object @event
attributes :code, :address...
```

And I need to return the integer values of :code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `Enumerize` [readme](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) on github it states that using `.code_value` gets the value of the enumeration while `.code` simply returns the name of the enumeration. That being said, I am not familiar with `rabl` or its conventions, though if I were simply to guess, try `:code_value`.

Let me know how it works, sorry if this is of no help.

Comment: @Ricardo don't forget, you can do `:code => :code_value` in Rabl.

Comment: @DamienRoche, only to post, I had to use the inverse way to works like I expected, `attributes code_value: :code`. Thank you very much.